# Python program with a wx.Frame to return a value

Tags: python, wxpython, return-value

I'm trying to return a value from a form. I'm not talking about create a dialog class, or use any type of an existing dialog. I've already have a form (wx.Frame) working and now, in certain cases, I need to get a return value from it, exactly if it were a Dialog.

For instance, my menu program call a program :

```
def chamaPais(self, event):
    app1 = wx.App()
    frm = FrmPais()
    app1.MainLoop()
    frm.Destroy()
    app1.Destroy()
```

I cannot change the FrmPais application, but sometimes I need to get a return value from it. It could be an object, an integer value a string value, whatever.

Thanks for any help and excuse me for not publish the entire code. I though it was not necessary in this case.

Comment: If you need something that works like a dialog use a dialog. There is no need to reinvent the wheel. You are misusing WX objects.

Comment: The frame can only return a value if that value is set in the `__init__` function. The interactive nature of a Gui is controlled by the event loop under supervision of the `MainLoop`. Any value set in the `__init__` function i.e. `self.value = "abcd"` would be available, in this case as `frame.value`